# Running onEdit trigger when sheet is updated by Zapier

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, zapier

I have a Google spreadsheet where I would like to automatically update one field every time a new row is added by a Zapier automation.

Every time I test the script manually by adding a row or making edits on existing rows, the script fires as expected. However, when Zapier adds a new row to the spreadsheet absolutely nothing happens.

Any idea why and how I can remedy this problem?

This the script which I am trying to use:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().
        getRange(row, 10).setValue('My_New_Value');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to replicate the behavior you are seeing in your script.  I believe that when you add a row outside of the active data range, it does not trigger an edit event.  In order to catch those events, you will also need to catch chagne events.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange

```
function onOpen ()
{ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunctionx")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onChange()
   .create();
 }
```

Looking at the documentation for a change event, you can detect that a row was inserted, but the row number is not returned.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change

```
function myFunctionx(e) {
    Logger.log("Change3");
    Logger.log(e.changeType);
}
```

You might be able to find the row that was inserted by looking at the last row in the active range.

```
function myFunctionx(e) {
    Logger.log("Change3");
    Logger.log(e.changeType);
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getLastRow());
}
```

It is possible for a change to affect more than one row if you copy and paste into multiple cells.  You should loop through all of the rows in your range.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    for(var i=e.range.getRow(); i<= e.range.getLastRow(); i++) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().
            getRange(i, 10).setValue(e.range.getA1Notation());
    }
}
```

Comment: `onEdit` (simple and installable triggers) are only triggered when a a user edits the spreadsheet by using the Google Sheets UI. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 1):

[`onChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) does trigger every time a new row is added(through sheets API).

```
function zapOnChange(e){
  if(e.changeType !== 'INSERT_ROW') return;//exit if the type of change is not a row insertion
  const insertedRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  //do something with inserted row
}
```

#### Important notes:

- Sheets API runs asynchronously. `onChange` is triggered randomly and NOT in the order of insertion.
- For eg, Two simultaneous inserts may occur at `A2:F2` and `A3:F3`, But the insertRow at `A2:F2` may trigger `onChange`  after insertion of `A3:F3`. **So, at the time `zapOnChange()` is run, the last row might already be `A3:F3`. So, you cannot use [`.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow) to determine the inserted row, but use [`.getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)**
- Sometimes multiple rows are inserted: [`.getActiveRange().getNumRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows) provides number of inserted rows.