# Trigger Google script without Form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, zapier

I have a Google script that runs on a trigger on form submit.

When the form is submitted a new row is added to a linked spreadsheet, and the script runs some actions to create a new folder and Google doc.

**I'd like to amend this by adding new rows via Zapier and not the form sumbission.**

Adding the new Rows with Zapier is easy,

However, in setting the script trigger to the **'On change'** event from **'On form submit'**, I get the error;

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I think in using the `e.values` that the script is expecting these from the form submission, but is failing because they are absent in Zapier added rows.

**Problem:**
I don't know how to resolve the error and allow the script to run in the same way when a form is submitted as when a new row is added from Zapier?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJuRw.png

---

What I have in place;

```
    function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
    var Timestamp = e.values[0];
    var NAME = e.values[1];
  
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234');
    var folder = createNewFolder(); 
    var copy = file.makeCopy(NAME, folder); 
    var newId = copy.getId();
  
    try{
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId).addEditor(email);
    }
    catch(error){
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId);
    }
  
    var body = doc.getBody();  
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', Name);
    doc.saveAndClose();                                             
                                       
    }

    <!--This creates a Google drive folder -->

    function createNewFolder() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var names = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var POSNAME = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),
    2).getValue(); 
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(NAME);
    while (folders.hasNext()) { 
    folder = folders.next();    
    if(folder.getName()==NAME){
     return folder;
        }
    }
    var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1234");
    return parentFolder.createFolder(NAME);
    }
```

Comment: The event object for onFormSubmit trigger is completely different from that of an onChange trigger [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).  Or you can Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); and actually look at the event object.  BTW  it only detects new rows added by a user not by a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a level within your value array and you need conver your `e` into a `range` before grabbing the values. Remember spreadsheets always have two-dimensional arrays.

I set the below code up in blank spreadsheet to run on edit and it's bringing the values into cells `a1` and `b1`. It's got excessive variables just to illustrate what's happening. You could obviously reduce these but ultimately I think this gets you the values you're looking for your variables `Timestamp` and `NAME`.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
const mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
function onEdit(e){
  var theRange = e.range;
    var allValues = theRange.getValues();
    var singleRowValues = allValues[0];
    var firstColumnofRowValue = singleRowValues[0];
    var secondColumnofRowValue = singleRowValues[1];
    var Timestamp = firstColumnofRowValue;
    var NAME = secondColumnofRowValue;
    //Test Output
    mySS.getRange("A1").offset(0,0,1,2).setValues([[Timestamp,NAME]]);
}
```

Comment: The OP asked to go from an onFormSubmit to onChange.  There is no e.range in an onChange.  In addition, onChange is an installable trigger.

Comment: Yeah but OP mentioned adding rows, so I'm taking a guess that this is true intent. We'll see.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @PGSystemTester Ahhh! it does work but only when adding rows within sheets, I have seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083786/google-apps-script-onedit-trigger-not-firing-when-zapier-adds-a-row) now about this not triggering with any Google API added rows. This means my Zapier added rows won't work.

I don't see too much in other posts to suggest there is a way around this, so might need to get creative, any ideas?

Comment: @EwanFarry, I was actually a little worried about something like this as events can't trigger other events (which is probably a good thing). I'm not that famaliar with Zapier, but I am pretty strong with Google App Scripts related to forms tied to spreadsheets (an underrated set of tools in my opinion). Since you asked for my ideas, I'd suggest sticking with the onForm Submission event and doing the coding either using GAS yourself or setup an array function in sheets to do whatever you want.