Is there a google apps script trigger for when a filter changes?
I want to run a function after I change a filter (when data is filtered out or when the filter's sort changes). I have tried the simple triggers onEdit, onSelectionChange, and the installable trigger onChange, but none of them are triggered when I change the filter.
Using onEdit
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== "Sheet3") return;
  let range = sheet.getRange("E1");
  range.setValue(new Date());
}

Using onChange
In my attept to use onChange, I ran the following script and gave permissions to google to install the trigger. In my testing, the trigger worked when I added data to the filtered table, but did not run when I simply changed the filter.
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onChange")
  .forSpreadsheet("1ryPr3P8d49J-XFiMo1utzy7Qc29xZXyermqnvNfrpK4")
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function onChange(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== "Sheet3") return;
  let range = sheet.getRange("E1");
  range.setValue(new Date());
}

Is there a way to run a method when a filter is changed?

Are you sure you have correctly configured your onChange trigger? It is supposed to run in the situations you describe.

@user27425627 See my edit for how I tried onChange

@redmoncoreyl For triggers that only require setting once, in my opinion, it's better to create them by using the Apps Script user interface. In this case, only you can verify that the spreadsheet id is correct; people trying to replicate the issue should use a different spreadsheet id :) Tip: Add Logger.log / console.log to validate your assumptions, i.e., you could log the sheet name to validate that the correct sheet is got as the active sheet.

The problem
After playing around a bit, here's where I believe the issue lies: not within the trigger, but rather within the getActiveSheet method.
When you run these lines:
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() !== "Sheet3") return;

, my guess is that sheet.getName() is never 'Sheet3', regardless of where the filtering or sorting event took place.
Indeed, as described in this other question, the getActiveSheet method does not work properly. As stated in the documentation, it is supposed to

[get] the active sheet in a spreadsheet. The active sheet in a spreadsheet is the sheet that is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI.

When editing a certain sheet, the latter does indeed become active. The same is true whenever a row or column is inserted/removed, and when a cell is formatted.
Nonetheless, data seems to suggest that, when dealing with other types of events, it returns the same sheet any time it is invoked, that may or may not be the active sheet. This includes filtering and sorting of data.
I tested this myself, with identic result. With the following function being triggered through the onChange event:
function onChange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(sheet.getName());
}

; I consistently see this on my screen:

Whenever I filter or sort the table, even though Sheet2 is active, the method returns Sheet1.
Failed attempts at solving it
The aforementioned SO question suggests a possible solution involving adding a custom menu to the UI; in this case that doesn't work. Using SpreadsheetApp.flush() doesn't help either.
Is there some order in this chaos? In my case, the method always returns the first sheet in the sequence of tabs, regardless of their order of creation. However, in the case of the linked question's OP, it was the middle (second) sheet... So I'm not sure about the consistency here.
A Google Issue Tracker has been created; if the reader wants to track and/or star it, to make Google prioritise this issue, see References below.
The workaround
I can offer an unsatisfying partial workaround. The onChange trigger does not have a range object, so it is tough to work with. It does have, however, an changeType property.
This property describes the type of event: row/column insertion/deletion, editing, formatting, etc. There isn't a SORT, nor a FILTER option, but both of those are included in the OTHER type. We can work with that so as to trigger your function only when a event takes place that is not one of the specified types:
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType === 'OTHER') {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
    const range = sheet.getRange("E1");
    range.setValue(new Date());
  }
}

Two caveats:

it would encompass other types of events - such as protecting a sheet or a range;
it would also run whenever data is filtered or sorted in different sheets.

Otherwise, the best solution would be, as @Wicket suggested initially, to have a sidebar with custom JavaScript that polls the spreadsheet.
References

Event objects
Google Issue Tracker 1 (made by OP)
Google Issue Tracker 2, current status: assigned 07-2023
Google Issue Tracker 3, current status: assigned 07-2023


@redmoncoreyl if you confirm that this is indeed the problem, and for any future reader, I haven't been able to find an open issue on Google Issue Tracker. If you want, (after double-checking that it doesn't already exist), you can create one and edit my answer to add the link so others may star and/or follow the issue.

Yes, I have confirmed that the reason my code isn't working as intended is that getActiveSheet doesn't work properly. When I make the onChange function simply create an alert, changing the filter DOES open an alert.

For my purposes, the problems mentioned at the bottom of the answer will not cause any issue, so for now I accept this answer.

You say "when dealing with other types of events, it returns the same sheet any time it is invoked, that may or may not be the active sheet." Do you have any idea what sheet getActiveSheet decides to return after the filter event? Is it always the first sheet in the sequence of tabs?

It is a good question. In my case: yes, regardless of when the sheets where created. However, in the case of the linked question's OP, it was the middle (second) sheet... So I'm not sure about the consistency here.

I can confirm that it's always the left most sheet that is returned on getActiveSheet(), on filtering.

That was also usually the case for users who faced this problem in 2014, when the issue concerned not only sorting and filtering events, but any event.

@user27425627 I'm sure that's not the case with row inserts now... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63842000/  This was especially useful with Row inserts from external api calls, which essentially acted as a Sheets api call trigger https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423975/

In the case of filtering, getActiveRange() directly on ss returned " You must set a active sheet first", which says there's no active sheet and therefore  getActiveSheet() is obviously bluffing.

That's interesting. And indeed it works fine with inserts and other methods; what I meant before is that maybe deep down it is the same issue than in 2014, which got fixed for every event but these ones.

@TheMaster Yes, I tried getActiveRange() in the triggered function and got an error with the same "you must set an active sheet first."

@redmoncoreyl You might wanna add this stackoverflow question link to the issue tracker as there are at least 3 users here who confirmed the issue publicly.

In fact, not just the first sheet that the getActiveSheet().getName() will return. For my case, in my installable onEdit() trigger, even Sheet2 may be returned when Sheet3 is active. But when you click through all sheets one after another and try again, it may work. But when you press Ctrl+Z to undo something, it no longer detect the active sheet name correctly again.
